# How to prevent windows 10 from installing games on my device?

Tags: windows

So for some reason windows is installing games on my windows machine automatically.

If I search the game name in the start menu, they don't even appear there!?

[image]

Comment: This is not really a question for SO, where is the CODE issue? I am surprised you ask this here with your rep level....

Comment: @ThomasG You are right, but I think the other sub sites of stackoverflow are not that used that much, and to me, recently it feels more like SO is for all computer related questions. For example https://superuser.com/ looks a bit dead. Again I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
Windows Store -> Setting > turn off Automatic updates
[as in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11UyS.png)